# Hide text outside margin in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

Is there a way to hide those parts of a textbox that are outside the page margins? In the screenshot below, I want the line to stop at the margins. Or is there another (better?) way to achieve the same aim?

[image]

Comment: Hi lowercasename, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the text **frame** with the Selection Tool and Copy it.

Draw a rectangular picture frame

`Edit > Paste Into`

Set the picture frame to the margin width.

---

Or the way many may do it... draw white rectangles to cover things. A method I try and avoid.

Comment: I was afraid that white rectangles would be the only solution...

Comment: @lowercasename I've edited, there's actually no need to outline the type. Just copy the text frame and paste that into a picture frame.